# Unable to reload angular component when value changes in service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-services, angular-components

I am using 4 modules in my angular application *AppModule, AdminModule, HomeModule, UIModule*. Base module is AppModule, UIModule is where shared components are declared. I have a *MenuBarComponent* in UI Module, when the user changes to a different Menu, the Menu name will be updated on to a variable in GlobalVariableService and using an observable the admin component is reloaded based on the menu value in the GlobalVariableService.

The problem is when the *Admin Module* is not importing the UIModule, the subscription to the *GlobalVariableService* works fine and the admin component is getting updated. but when the UIModule is imported in the *AdminModule*, the subscription is not working.

Please let me know what is going wrong here.

**Globals.service.ts**

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

    export class Globals {

      private eventSubject = new Subject<any>();

      setEvent(): void {
        this.eventSubject.next(true);
      }

      resetEvent(): void {
        this.eventSubject = new Subject();
      }

      getEvent(): Observable<any> {
        return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
      }

      adminMenu:string = "adminPage"
    }
```

**Menu.Component.ts**

```
  changeHeader(obj: any) {
    this.global.adminMenu = "usersPage";
    this.global.setEvent();
  }
```

**admin.component.ts**

```
  private subscriptionList: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(public global: Globals) {
    this.subscriptionList.add(this.global.getEvent().subscribe());
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.global.resetEvent();
    this.subscriptionList.unsubscribe();
  }
```

**ui.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  exports: [MenuComponent],
})
```

**admin.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    UiModule
  ]
})
```

Comment: Hi Arvi, welcome! For this kind of problems, you should provide a full example, because it can be the imports in your Base module (AppModule) or some other piece of code you are missing and could help us to solve this problem! If you can, provide the same scenario here https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I think the problem is this.global.resetEvent(); you are killing the old subject not cleaning the current one, you can set next(null) instead of instanciate a new one

Comment: @BrianDucca - Please find the project github link [Github](https://github.com/AravindhRajGS/StackOverFlow).

**[expected behaviour]** - Select a value in the dropdown and click on refresh, corresponding component will get loaded.

**[issue]** - if you uncomment the uiModule import in AdminModule, the app is working as expected, but if you import the uiModule in Admin Module, the components are not loading.

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz - Thanks for the comment, but it didn't work. please find the github link for the project. [Github](https://github.com/AravindhRajGS/StackOverFlow).

Comment: which dropdown? it ask me to log in, after bypass the login i dont see any dropdown @Arvi